# SPO list with custom form in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio

I want to attach a custom list form using Visual Studio. After I added a form my solution explorer looks like this:

[image: List with form]

I also changed the `Deployment Type` of the `Test.aspx` to "ElementFile". Now I stiwched over to the `Schema.xml` of the list and try to change it inside the -part:

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Test.aspx"  SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />      
</Forms>
```

Deployment to SPO works but after that the original create-form is shown.

I used SPD 2013 to create a form and then used `_vti_bin/owssvr.dll...` to export the schema. It is using something like this:

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Name="{B1726E3E-79E4-445C-A242-4BF74D5C7C7A}" Url="Lists/Testliste/Test.aspx" Default="TRUE" FormID="0"/>
```

I tried to use the path in my xml:

- Used it `Url` -> nothing happens besides that the url in the browser changes when I hit new but the site is the default one
- Used in `SetupUrl` -> deployment to SPO fails without any details

So what exactly do I have to enter in the schema.xml?

Comment: OK. My sdolution will be: I switch over to develop all my UI components by hand using HTML5 and JavaScript. I wanted to use MVC but customer doesn't have Azure Subscription and Auto-Hosted apps are no longer supported. Just wanted to let you people know.